# image link concatenation with ejs syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concatenation, ejs, string-concatenation

I am trying to build an `<img src=` link concatenation in a .ejs file. A part of the link is coming from a json file, build in my .js file.

The image shall be shown on my website.

Maybe it is just the syntax, I am very new to the topic.

I tried to add   <%= user.thumbnail%>

```
<p class="name">Name: <%= user.name %></p> // to get the name, this is working

<p class="thumbnail"><img src="https://website/character/ + <%= user.thumbnail%> "></p>   // is not working

<p class="thumbnail"><img src="https://website/character/ + '<%= user.thumbnail%>'"></p>   // is also not working
```

Thanks for help :)

*edit:*

index.js:

```
var last = "last/part/oflink.jpg";
var thumbnail= "https://firstpartoflink/character/" + last;
```

all I want is to show the image in the ejs file, like

index.ejs:

```
<p class="thumbnail"><img src="  SyntaxToGetThumbnailVar  " /> </p>
```

Comment: `https://website/character/<%= user.thumbnail%>`? EJS only treats `<% %>` blocks as JavaScript. Looking at the wrong output probably gives a pretty good hint.

Comment: ok, thx for your fast reply. I tried it with a normal variable. The link which could show the picture is now in "var thumbnail", but I don't get it, how can I get the content of my var from js to ejs?

Comment: there are examples with 
<img src="<%= document.data.illustration.url %>" /> but if it is not possible to concatenate, then the link have not to come from the json, so I could use a variable, right? I just need the picture shown in .ejs file

Comment: None of what you’re saying makes sense, sorry. If you’re getting an error, please edit the error into your question. If you’re getting the wrong HTML, show that HTML.

Comment: I edited after your comment, maybe it is clearer now

Comment: How are you passing `thumbnail` to the template rendering call?

Comment: hey, i didn't find time to answer your question before, but thanks again for helping me and bringing me on the right track :)

Comment: You can concat string inside the "<%=" tag. Example <img src="<%= './image/' + props.image %>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

index.js:

```
.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var data = { 'user': { 
        'thumbnail' : g_chardata.thumbnail
    } 
     };
   res.render('index', data)
})
```

index.ejs:

```
<!-- Build Image Link from Json and string -->
        <p id="image" style="display: none"><%= user.thumbnail %></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var pic = document.getElementById("image").innerText;
            document.getElementById('thumbnail').src = 'https://link.com/character/' + pic;
        };
        </script>
        <!-- Show Thumbnail Bild -->
        <img src="" id="thumbnail"/>
```

Happy greetings :)

Answer (score 1):

[image link concatenation with ejs syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936969/image-link-concatenation-with-ejs-syntax)

If I understand correctly, the final link consists of two variables from different sources:

1. controller
2. json file

Variables passed from controller to view are interpreted by EJS through <% variable %>. For the other hand, I am considering the json file is read from client side. So, they are interpreted at different moments.
Probably you have something like this:

```
// Controller
res.render("myView", { user: { thumbnail: 'partial-path' }});

// View
<html>
    ...
    <p class="thumbnail"><img src="https://website/character/<%= user.thumbnail %>"></p>
    ...
    <script src="myJson.js"></script>
    ...
</html>
```

A possible solution is hide image at the rendering time and get the last part of the link from JSON file using JavaScript. After that just set `src` with the final link:

```
<html>
    ...
    <p class="thumbnail"><img id="someId" style="display: none" src="https://website/character/<%= user.thumbnail %>"></p>
    ...
    <script src="myJson.js"></script>
    <script>
        var linkPart = myJsonObj.someProperty;
        var el = document.getElementById('someId');
        el.src = el.src + linkPart;
        el.style.display = '';
    </script>
    ...
</html>
```

I hope this helps you solve the problem ;)

Comment: hey, yes, thank you :) thats it or at least very close to my running version :)))